# For $\{T_n\}$ and $T$ positive and self-adjoint, show $T_n \stackrel{SR}{\to} T$ iff $(T_n + I)^{-1} \stackrel {s}{\to} (T + I)^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, strong-convergence

For $\{T_n\}$ and $T$ positive and self-adjoint, show $T_n \stackrel{SR}{\to} T$ (i.e. $T_n \to T$ in the strong resolvent sense) iff $(T_n + I)^{-1} \stackrel {s}{\to} (T + I)^{-1}$ (i.e. $(T_n + I)^{-1} \to (T + I)^{-1}$ strongly).

Not sure where to go with this one. I know that by definition $T_n \stackrel{SR}{\to} T$ if and only if $(\lambda I - T_n)^{-1} \stackrel {s}{\to} (\lambda I - T)^{-1}$ for $\lambda$ with $Im(\lambda) \neq 0$.

For the forward direction, I first thought it was trivial and that I could just use the special case $\lambda = 1$, but of course $Im(1) = 0$, so I can't.

Comment: Sorry if this is a pesky question -- I'm asking to learn. What does the $s$ above the arrow mean, i.e., what's the definition of $(T_n - I)^{-1} \to (T - I)^{-1}$? Does it stand for strong topology or mean something other than convergence with respect to operator norm?

Comment: @JonWarneke, it's not a pesky question at all, and I guess I shouldn't have assumed everyone knows the notation. I'm just going through Simon and Reed and that's what they use. $s$ indeed stands for strong convergence or convergence in the strong operator topology. So in this case $\|(T_n - I)^{-1}(x) - (T - I)^{-1}(x) \| \to 0$ $\forall x$.

Comment: But now something is off. What happens if $T-I$ is not invertible? If $T=I$, $T_n=(1-1/n)I$, then you will have $T_n\xrightarrow{SR} T$, but the other side of the implication makes no sense.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, I'm not sure, but that's the statement of the problem. And by ${}^{-1}$, I think it's meant $\frac{1}{T_n-I}$ and so on rather than the inverse (although I guess that is the inverse). But given the statement it seems it's assumed that it _is_ invertible.

Comment: Are you trying to do problem 28, page 315 in Reed-Simon? If that's the case, the question you ask is not what the problem asks.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, problem 27 actually.

Comment: Then you wrote a couple minus signs that should have been plusses.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, damn, you're right, I'll edit it right away. I think everything is correct now, including the definition of strong resolvent.